# Totaling multiple lines into once cell with different date formats

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I want to search through a column of dates in the format **YYYY-MM-DD** (column G - in a random order) and sum up all corresponding cost values for all dates in the same month.

[image: sheets]

So, for example, the total cost for December 2019 would be 200.

My current formula is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(G2:G6)=12)*(YEAR(G2:G6)=2019)*(H2:H6))
```

This gives me the total cost for that month correctly, but I cannot work out how to do this without hardcoding the year and month!

How would I do this with a formula (given the two date columns are a different format)?

Comment: Have a look into `SUMIFS`, column `G` seems like it's all you need. Check for `MONTH` and `YEAR`. If that assumption is incorrect, then please update your question with more details as to why and how you want to incorporate the two different columns.

Comment: I have updated my question^ I need the month columns on the left as I have another application reading these values to plot a monthly graph of total cost

Comment: What about Pivot Tables? You can create a Pivot Table grouping by month, and getting the values you need, and combine that with a Pivot Chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily combining SUMIFS with EDATE:

[image]

> **[SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)**
>
> **[EDATE function](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/edate-function-3c920eb2-6e66-44e7-a1f5-753ae47ee4f5)**

The formula I've used in cell B2 is:

```
=SUMIFS($F$2:$F$6;$E$2:$E$6;">="&A2;$E$2:$E$6;"<="&(EDATE(A2;1)-1))
```

For this formula to work, in **column A must be first day of each month!**. In cell `A2` the value is `01/11/2019`, but applied a format of `mmmm yyyy` to see it like that (and chart will do the same).

Answer (score 1):

paste in **D2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({EOMONTH(G2:G, -1)+1, H2:H}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
    and not Col1 = date '1900-01-01' 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col2)'' 
  format Col1 'mmm yyyy'", 0))
```

[image: 0]